# c# Enumerable.Sum change return type

Tags: c#, types, enumerable

Hello it is possible to change Sum return type without changing type of enumerable?

```
string func(int a)
{
    return (from el in Enumerable.Range(0, a >> 1) select el << 1).Sum().ToString();
}
```

I want to get Sum() as int64 of

```
(from el in Enumerable.Range(0, a >> 1) select el << 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sum *always* uses the type of the enumerable (or the result type of the mapping function) and has [overloads for the different numeric types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.sum%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). In this case, simply alter the Select as so to get the values to be added as longs<sup>1</sup> (and the result to be a long).

```
// uses: long Enumerable.Sum(IEnumerable<long> t)
(.. select (long)(el << 1)).Sum()
```

Or, use the overload that takes in a mapping function.

```
// uses: long Enumerable.Sum(IEnumerable<T> t, Func<T,long> f)
(.. select el << 1).Sum(i => (long)i)
```

To only get the result as a different type (without affecting the type used for the summation), simply perform the cast/conversion at the end. Because this only changes the type *after* the summation it affects precision and range/overflow during the Sum function differently than the first two methods shown.

```
(long)(.. select el << 1).Sum()
```

---

<sup>1</sup> In C#, `long` *is* `System.Int64`.